# How to use the default template for Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I installed Django and enabled the admin site. When I go to the admin page, I get the following[image]

The image does not look the official Django tutorial. In `settings.py` I updated `TEMPLATE_DIRS` with the correct path.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/var/www/mysite/templates/admin"
)
```

I also tried restarting Apache many times. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issued related to static files rather than templates:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools on your browser to looks at what requests are being made. Most likely some static files like CSS, etc. are not being served up.